# Authentication to offline device

Tags: authentication, digital-signature

I have an offline safe at a remote location that I want to give people access to at my discretion. I would like to control who and when they have access, without having to travel to the safe.

Example:

- I would like "Peter" to be able to open the safe, which is at a remote location, tomorrow.
- In my office, I sign the text "January 30, 2021" with my private key and give it to Peter.
- Peter travels to the safe and enters the signed text into the safe.
- The safe verifies the signature with a corresponding public key.
- The safe checks the current date and opens itself.

Problem:
The signed text is very long. The safe would have a keypad and a small screen, but entering more than 10 or 20 characters would be difficult.

To solve it, I'm thinking about e-banking solutions. They started with cross-off-lists. Such a list could be used where each number on the list could be assigned to a date. Now, I'd like to avoid shared secrets and cross-off lists.

Banks moved to mechanisms like photoTan where they display a QR code to the user; the user scans it with their smartphone, then get a short sequence which they enter back into the banking website.

Such a thing would work. I would like to perform such a "proof" where the safe can send a long challenge to the user, but the user can only respond with a short challenge-response. What are those algorithms?

Comment: Instead of having them to enter digital signature, use smart card which will certify the challenge sent by the vault.

Answer (score 1):

You could use OTP for this.

Create a random secret and add it on the safe and your phone. When you want Peter to access the safe, you use your phone to pick a future date and generate the token, and send it to Peter. That token could be valid for an hour, or six, or a day, so adjust your generation algorithm accordingly.

That would create an issue when you want two or more people to access the safe at the same time. This could be adjusted by having 10 OTP secrets on the safe (0 to 9), and you concatenate the index of the selected key to the password.

Let's say the OTP for "January 30, 2021" on the secret 2 is `83641398`, so Peter would have to enter `283641398` on the safe, and Jane would have secret 1, and her token would be something like `1977433`. The safe would get the first digit to identify the secret, calculate the token, and authenticate the user. 9 digits is long enough to deter bruteforce, and short enough to be entered on seconds.

As an OTP is time-dependent, you have to keep a clock on the safe. It does not need to be accurate to the second, because the token life would be at least a couple hours, so even a 15 minute drift would not bring much difficulties to Peter or Jane.

And being time-dependent, the password don't have to be revoked later, and it would be useless on the next day.

Comment: I would like to avoid shared secrets, since, with secrets, I could work with sufficiently long cross-off lists. OTP uses a shared secret. There's U2F which doesn't, but also doesn't work with short challenge-responses but requires some sort of yubikey or NFC interface. Ideally, I would have an arbitrary number of users. I don't mind if they have to enter their user names before the whole authentication sequence starts, this is also the case with e-banking solutions. But I don't want the safe to have a user list.

Comment: The secret is only shared between you and the safe. And it does not matter how much users you have, as long as the concurrent users are less than 10, or less than 100 (so you have to put 100 secrets on the safe).

Comment: Thanks but according to the original question, i am looking for a solution without shared secrets.

Comment: There's no way. You cannot authenticate something unless both parties know part of the secret. On TLS, one side have the public key and the other have the private key. On common password authentication, one side have the password and the another have the hash. On the daily mechanical lock, the lock have the secret and the physical key have the indentations. There's no authentication without sharing some form of secret between the parties.

Comment: When you visit a stackexchange.com for the very first time in your life, the website authenticates itself towards you through TLS Server Authentication. Of course you do not share a secret with this website. The public key is not secret by definition. It is distributed to everyone that visits the website.

Comment: You **do have** a shared secret, it's the CA Certificates. There's a list of them on your browser and OS. StackExchange says that LetsEncrypt certified them, and your browser checks its side of the secret to see if the site is telling the truth.

Comment: The Root CA Certificates that the browser uses contains no secrets. I do not ask for an explanation of PKI. It is neither my question nor do I lack knowledge in this area. I would ask that you stick to the question and answer if you feel proficient in the area. Thank you.

Comment: I am proficient in the area, and that's why I can say that what you are trying to accomplish cannot be done.

Comment: Your rationale is the denial of the existence of asymmetric encryption.